# Why function not working well after make it async function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

There was a non-async function and I made it as async function by using `async` keyword.

Befor:

```
exports.allowed = function (page, username) {}
```

After:

```
exports.allowed = async function (page, username) {}
```

But after making it async function is not working properly.

```
exports.allowed = async function (page, username) {
   //method body
}

exports.getMenu = function (selected, username) {
    const menu = [
     [
       ['/sss', 'sss'],
       ['/yyy', 'yyy'],
     ]
    ];

    for (let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
       menu[i] = menu[i].filter((item) => this.allowed(item[0], username));
    }
}
```

Once I remove the `async` keyword, then code works properly. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Async functions return `Promise`. See this example

```js
function first() { return 2 }

typeof first() // number

async function second() { return 2 }

second() instanceof Promise // true
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a function as `async` it returns a `promise`.

```js
let three = () => 3;
let asyncThree = async () => 3;

console.log(three());
asyncThree().then(value => console.log(value));
```

In your example, you'll have to do something like this:

```js
let allowed = async function(page, username) {
  return page !== '/sss';
}

let getMenu = async function(selected, username) {
  const menu = [
    [
      ['/sss', 'sss'],
      ['/yyy', 'yyy'],
    ]
  ];

  return Promise.all(menu.map(async items => {
    let alloweds = await Promise.all(items.map(item => allowed(item[0], username)));
    return items.filter((_, i) => alloweds[i]);
  }));
}

getMenu().then(menu => console.log(menu));
```

Comment: Updated for your scenario.

Comment: No. You added a few trivial lines to your question that don't affect the core question. Just add those lines to my answer as well. Stackoverflow isn't a "solve my homework for me".